# Why executables have to be recompiled

Tags: c++, linux, executable

I was wondering why executables (written in c++) have to be recompiled from sources on every linux machine, even if the machines are software and hardware the same?

I had a search engine, written in c++, and I have to recompile it every time I want to move it on a new linux machine to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does it mean to `compile executable` ?

Comment: to have a cpp file/files and to make an executable out of them using g++/gcc

Comment: this is called sources, not executables

Comment: They don't always have to be recompiled. A lot of linux distributions use package managers to install pre-compiled binaries.

Comment: @Andrew: although strictly one compiles the sources *to* an executable, it's not uncommon in English to talk about compiling the executable *from* the sources. I don't think it can be called incorrect, since there's no other possible meaning. There could be some ambiguity with VMs, though, since you can compile from the source to an intermediate format (e.g. Java bytecode) and then compile from the bytecode to native instructions (as in a JIT). I've never actually seen this ambiguity cause misunderstandings, and I've worked on a JIT implementation.

Comment: Equally you could say that one doesn't "compile a magazine from articles". You could be a stickler and say that one compiles the articles into a magazine. But I don't think many people would seriously argue that it's incorrect usage of the verb "compile".

Comment: Did you only recompile it or did you have to install it again on the new computer?

Comment: It's a system, developed by our inhouse developers, so there is no installation - I just have to build the executable from the cpp/h files every time. If I copy the binary and paste it on another machine it does not work (I think it returned Segmentation fault).

Comment: You certainly don't have to do this as long as the environiment on those machines is similar. Most likely you were missing some other libraries that get built, or the compilation does some additional configuration etc

Comment: Your search engine, or it's installer, is broken.  The installer should make all necessary libraries available and ensure that permissions/privileges are such that they are accessible.  Sounds like maybe you have the Linux equivalent 'DLL hell', but it has to be said that I have never, ever rebuilt any Windows EXE on the target machine - 99.9% of the time, it just works.  Hit your inhouse developers about the head with a 'Linux for Dummies' book <g>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking why an executable compiled on Linux-X won't run on Linux-Y, then the reason is probably that dynamic libraries (.so) are missing or could not be found.

EDIT: oh sorry, looks like I didn't read your question well enough. Removed the sarcasm.

Comment: +1 / Sometimes the linked libraries may be sought in directories specified in environment variables, so even if the libraries are in the same places it might not work if the user shells are configured differently.

Comment: Sadly, my list of Linux apps that will not run 'out-of-the-box' because of libs/paths/permissions/privileges issues is rather large:(  I quickly get tired of patching lucky-seven 'chmod 0777' all over the place to get stuff to work.

Answer (score 2):

It normally shouldn't be necessary to recompile. Many applications are distributed as executables and they work fine.

What errors do you get when you just copy the executable and run it on a different machine?

Maybe the problem is with the way you're copying the executable, it might be corrupting it.

Answer (score 1):

The recompilation is ensuring you get optimal performance on your machine, because each time the configuration script is running to find dependencies and settings. This also ensures the openness of software as its source is always available and is modifiable by an appropriate agents - that is us.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily the case. Consider how Ubuntu packages are installed for example - https://askubuntu.com/questions/162477/how-are-packages-actually-installed-via-apt-get-install

Apparently these are not compiled from source on the destination machine, but installed as pre-built binaries. Having said that, it is generally a good idea to build binaries from source on the machine that they will run on as you will avoid potential problems such having incompatible shared libraries (such as libc) which can occur when building something on Linux X and running on Linux Y.